# Editing datagridviewComboboxcolumn at run time

Tags: c#, datagridview

Im trying to search in dataGridviewcomboboxcoulmn at run time...but no succeeded .

```
  private void dataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cel = dataGridView2.CurrentCell;
        DataGridViewRow r = dataGridView2.CurrentRow;


        if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Tracked");
            if (cel == r.Cells[0])
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl c = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
                c.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code works. It's very unclear what the problem is though — your code isn't searching for anything.  That's a terrible place for a MessageBox, by the way.

Comment: yeah same code is working on my another project

Comment: Make sure you have the event wired up correctly.  If you copied this code, then the event won't automatically run.

Comment: not didnt copied..i added the event manualy

Comment: Well, use the debugger. Put a stop on the first line in your code and look at the values as you step line by line.